# circular array in c for a delay line

Tags: c, audio, circular-buffer

I'm trying to find any resources online for programming a delay line in c.

I tried implementing this one here

https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/doppler/Variable_Delay_Line_Software.html.

The problem with this is where it says

```
A[wptr++] = x;
```

The compiler throws an error because wptr is a pointer and not an integer.

Could somebody point me toward an example of a compiler friendly example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
    A[wptr++] = x; 
y = A[rptr++];
```

with:

```
    *(wptr++) = x;
y = *(rptr++);
```

Answer (score 1):

this should be:

```
*(wptr++) = x;
```